# How to implement Background Fetch on React Native | Expo?

Tags: react-native

There was a task to make push notifications when the application is completely off.

Need to implement some Background Task Manager that will be at intervals such as a minute to check for new notifications for a specific user. In simple words, make a background fetch.

Previously, I implemented push notifications in the application.But they work only when the application is enabled or simply minimized. When the app is completely off Push does not work.

Has anyone done this before ?

I use Expo for this project.